# How to render the content of an object in vue?

Tags: vue.js

apologies if that's too basic, but I'm stuck.

I have created an object in vue with three properties (slug, title and content). I successfully console.logged the object. How can I now use the object in my page in order to render its content?

There is no need for me to loop through the object, at it has only one item in it.

```
<template>
  <div class="relative py-16 overflow-hidden bg-white">
    <div class="relative px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div class="mx-auto text-lg max-w-prose">
        <h1>
          <span
            class="block text-base font-semibold tracking-wide text-center text-indigo-600 uppercase"
            >Hello</span
          >
          <span
            class="block mt-2 text-3xl font-extrabold leading-8 tracking-tight text-center text-gray-900 sm:text-4xl"
            >Here is the name</span
          >
        </h1>
        <p class="mt-8 text-xl leading-8 text-gray-700"></p>
        <div
          v-bind="this.data.content"
          class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
        ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
const Cosmic = require("cosmicjs");
const api = Cosmic();
const bucket = api.bucket({
  slug: "((BUCKETNAME))",
  read_key: "((KEY))",
});

const data = bucket
  .getObject({
    id: "((BUCKET ID))", // Object ID
    props: "slug,title,content", // get only what you need
  })
  .then((data) => {
    const about = data.objects;
    console.log(data);
  });

export default {
  name: "data",
  data() {
    return {
      data,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html

Comment: You need to read [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html#Base-Example), It'll help you to understand, how to fetch data and inject into your component

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters have suggested, it would be useful to read the Vue syntax guide here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html

But to answer your question with the most minimal of code changes, you'd want to move your data request to the lifecycle hook of your vue component.

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ dataObjects.title }}</h1>
  <p>{{ dataObjects.slug }}</p>
  <p>{{ dataObjects.content }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "data",
  data() {
    return {
      dataObjects: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    bucket.getObject({
      id: "((BUCKET ID))", // Object ID
      props: "slug,title,content", // get only what you need
    })
      .then((data) => {
        // Assign the return value to the dataObjects propery of the vue instance.
        this.dataObjects = data;
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

In the template section, you can see that I've used curly braces to render the contents of dataObjects (I wasn't sure what structure your data is in).

You can also learn from examples on the [Vue Cookbook site](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html)